# Instagram API Redirect URI SSL for localhost without the Warning

Tags: facebook, api, ssl, oauth, instagram-api

Instagram API requires redirect uris to have an SSL certificate (HTTPS connection).

I use Instagram API for my mobile app, and OAuth response should first invoke procedure in the app.

I am able to create a server to catch this call locally (on `127.0.0.1`), but for the certificate, I can only create a self-signed one. The problem is that the browsers don't trust it and initially warn the user about the potential hazards, which is unacceptable for the user experience.

I saw a few similar questions on Stackoverflow, but unfortunately, I couldn't understand if they solve my issue.

How to avoid this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution for my specific case; I use Flutter for the mobile application. But overall you can find something similar for other cases as well.

Initially, I was launching the Instagram authorization window with [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package. Basically, for iOS it launches the url in-app, but in a Safari Web View. In this way I am unable to control the flow in this web view. So, what I wanted to do is to catch a request to `127.0.0.1` when authorization is completed by running a local server in the app. It does work but throws a warning about security hazard due to a self-signed certificate, since Instagram requires `https` being used and `127.0.0.1` cannot have a trusted certificate.

Instead, now I launch the Instagram authorization window in-app with custom WebView using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter). It provides more flexibility, but most importantly I can track navigation. So now, Instagram redirects my user to the non-existing page on my website, which has a trusted certificate (but it doesn't really matter), but the aforementioned WebView can detect this redirect, parse the URL to retrieve the wanted code and prevent actual redirection by closing this web view. So, eventually, I get the wanted code in the app, so I can send it to my backend with extra user id reference.

So, basically, the workflow looks like this:

1. User clicks a button in the app to connect Instagram account;
2. The app launches a custom web view and opens Instagram authorization page;
3. After authorization, Instagram redirects the user to a dummy URL with the wanted code as a query parameter;
4. The custom web view detects this redirection;
5. Retrieves the code from the URL;
6. Closes web view (returns to the main app screen).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, even if they warns about https you can use api's. I had the same issue but I just tried to run the application on https port instead of http on localhost and it worked. So, Answer is you just need to run your application on https.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It does indeed work. The user must just accept the risks and view the page by clicking a corresponding button. Nevertheless, I suggest you would agree that this is an unacceptable workflow in production. The user shouldn't get a warning that my app is potentially trying to steal some data.

Just to clarify, I do run a server with a self-signed HTTPS on my mobile app to catch the wanted callback. The problem is that this https is not trusted, thus the warning.

Comment: Yes, I agree in production We need certificate and I installed certificate. But for local Development we can run for sale of development.

Comment: I think I was unclear about my setup. I have no issues with development, but rather in production. Localhost doesn't mean the development stage for my case. The mobile app, in production, will run this "server" locally on the mobile device in order to catch the callback from Instagram API. After authorization, Instagram redirects the user to a given URL in order to pass the credentials. I could theoretically give my main online backend endpoint instead, which has a trusted certificate, but then I don't know whose credentials are those. So I need to send it through the app itself with user id.

Comment: I suggest that your case is a website anyway, so when Instagram redirects the user to it, he is already identified from the cache. But for me, I cannot simply redirect the user to my API in the browser (and Instagram authorization happens in the mobile browser) in the way where API knows exactly what user it is, because the user is authorized in the app, not in the browser. But maybe I am trying to do this the wrong way?

Comment: @RomanShirokov I'm having trouble being able to use the instagram API, is it possible to use it and get the response from localhost? could someone help me with this?

Comment: Yes, we can use on local development environment for instagram API